# How to make boost::thread_group execute a fixed number of parallel threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

This is the code to create a thread_group and execute all threads in parallel:

```
boost::thread_group group;
for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
    group.create_thread(aFunctionToExecute);
group.join_all();
```

This code will execute all threads at once. What I want to do is to execute them all but 4 maximum in parallel. When on is terminated, another one is executed until there are no more to execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another, more efficient solution would be to have each thread callback to the primary thread when they are finished, and the handler on the primary thread could launch a new thread each time.  This prevents the repetitive calls to timed_join, as the primary thread won't do anything until the callback is triggered.

Comment: Finally end up with something like this:
I have a threadpool in which I register all the jobs. Then, I create the n threads and pass as argument to each thread the threadpool. Each thread checks whether there are jobs left. If yes, just get one job to execute. Otherwise, the thread ends.
This way, we just create n threads and not a thread per job (a job ends, a new thread is created).

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this:

```
    boost::mutex mutex_;
    boost::condition_variable condition_;
    const size_t throttle_;
    size_t size_;
    bool wait_;
    template <typename Env, class F>
    void eval_(const Env &env, const F &f) {
        {   
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_);
            size_ = std::min(size_+1, throttle_);
            while (throttle_ <= size_) condition_.wait(lock);
        }
        f.eval(env);
        {
            boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_);
            --size_; 
        }
        condition_.notify_one();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a [thread_pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) implementation, which is available [here](http://think-async.com/Asio/Recipes?skin=clean.nat,asio,pattern#A_thread_pool_for_executing_arbi).

Additionally I have noticed that if you create a vector of std::future and store  futures of many std::async_tasks in it and you do not have any blocking code in the function passed to the thread, VS2013 (atleast from what I can confirm) will launch exactly the appropriate no of threads your machine can handle. It reuses the threads once created.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own simplified interface of `boost::thread_group` to do this job:

```
class ThreadGroup : public boost::noncopyable
{
    private:
        boost::thread_group        group;
        std::size_t                maxSize;
        float                      sleepStart;
        float                      sleepCoef;
        float                      sleepMax;
        std::set<boost::thread*>   running;

    public:
        ThreadGroup(std::size_t max_size = 0,
                    float max_sleeping_time = 1.0f,
                    float sleeping_time_coef = 1.5f,
                    float sleeping_time_start = 0.001f) :
            boost::noncopyable(),
            group(),
            maxSize(max_size),
            sleepStart(sleeping_time_start),
            sleepCoef(sleeping_time_coef),
            sleepMax(max_sleeping_time),
            running()
        {
            if(max_size == 0)
                this->maxSize = (std::size_t)std::max(boost::thread::hardware_concurrency(), 1u);
            assert(max_sleeping_time >= sleeping_time_start);
            assert(sleeping_time_start > 0.0f);
            assert(sleeping_time_coef > 1.0f);
        }

        ~ThreadGroup()
        {
            this->joinAll();
        }

        template<typename F> boost::thread* createThread(F f)
        {
            float sleeping_time = this->sleepStart;
            while(this->running.size() >= this->maxSize)
            {
                for(std::set<boost::thread*>::iterator it = running.begin(); it != running.end();)
                {
                    const std::set<boost::thread*>::iterator jt = it++;
                    if((*jt)->timed_join(boost::posix_time::milliseconds((long int)(1000.0f * sleeping_time))))
                        running.erase(jt);
                }
                if(sleeping_time < this->sleepMax)
                {
                    sleeping_time *= this->sleepCoef;
                    if(sleeping_time > this->sleepMax)
                        sleeping_time = this->sleepMax;
                }
            }
            return *this->running.insert(this->group.create_thread(f)).first;
        }

        void joinAll()
        {
            this->group.join_all();
        }

        void interruptAll()
        {
#ifdef BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_INTERRUPTIONS
            this->group.interrupt_all();
#endif
        }

        std::size_t size() const
        {
            return this->group.size();
        }
    };
```

Here is an example of use, very similar to `boost::thread_group` with the main difference that the creation of the thread is a waiting point:

```
{
  ThreadGroup group(4);
  for(int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
    group.createThread(aFunctionToExecute);
} // join all at destruction
```