# serial boost thread joins in loop vs parallel in main

Tags: c++, loops, join, boost, blocking

In trying to understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6215646/1382306), I've found many similar questions and of course the docs but no explanation why.

Why is it that `join`s called in `main` can run parallel while `join`s called in a loop in `main` cannot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the sequence of events. It's the difference between

```
start thread 1
start thread 2
wait for thread 1 to finish
wait for thread 2 to finish
```

and

```
start thread 1
wait for thread 1 to finish

start thread 2
wait for thread 2 to finish
```

It should be obvious that, in the second case, the two threads never run at the same time.