# Multithreading mystery in C++ with Boost

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

```
static void testlock()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10000000;i++)
    {
        float f=2.0/i;
    }
}

static void TEST()
{
    cout<<"Start testing" <<endl;
    unsigned int startClock;

    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        startClock = clock();
        vector<boost::thread*> threads;
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            threads.push_back(new boost::thread(&testlock));
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            threads[j]->join();
            delete threads[j];
        }
        cout << i << " threads: "<< clock()-startClock << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Start testing
1 threads: 180000
2 threads: 350000
3 threads: 540000
4 threads: 730000
5 threads: 900000
6 threads: 1080000
7 threads: 1260000
8 threads: 1510000
9 threads: 1660000
10 threads: 1810000
```

I'm running this code on a quad core PC (Core2Quad, 4 cores no hyperthreading) so I expected 1-4 threads to take about the same time. Instead it seems as if only one core is being used. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Update:

-I'm using Eclipse CDT under Ubuntu Linux

-I tried the same with Pthread and I get the same result

Comment: I could be wrong, but construction `threads[j]->join(); delete threads[j];` means that we have to wait until thread will be finished

Comment: @VitalyDyatlov yes I start i threads at once then wait for them all to finish. The problem is that 4 threads should be executing at once but the output suggests otherwise.

Comment: FWIW, on my 6-core Win7 the output is as expected: Start testing
1 threads: 62
2 threads: 63
3 threads: 62
4 threads: 63
5 threads: 62
6 threads: 62
7 threads: 125
8 threads: 125
9 threads: 124
10 threads: 125

Comment: @ErwinJ problem is that `delete` wait until thread will be completed. So in a loop you wait for every single thread instead of running them simultaneously

Comment: Check your process affinity: maybe it's forced to use one core?

Comment: this could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344028/how-to-make-boostthread-group-execute-a-fixed-number-of-parallel-threads

Comment: What operating system?? As Igor says, process affinity could be an issue.

Comment: i would like to remark that indeed this is mystery. i tried using a thread_group + join_all instead of a vector, that did not solve it. also i tried using int's instead of floats.

Comment: @VitalyDyatlov, He starts all the threads, and then waits for all of them to finish. So they will be executing in parallel. Your linked question isn't really relevant.

Comment: @Roddy yes, sorry about join mistake.

Comment: @IgorR.How can I change the process affinity?

Comment: @ErwinJ. In task manager, right-click on the task and select "Set Affinity..." You should see all of your cores, hopefully all selected. You aren't by any chance actually running in a single-core VM are you? I see (with 12 cores) pretty much constant times output for the ten test cases.

Comment: @ErwinJ. Boost.Thread currently doesn't have such capability, so you have to use OS API. On Windows it looks like this: 1) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686223(v=vs.85).aspx 2) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @IgorR.: is this a comment because you're not sure? Otherwise, please make this an answer, so readers don't have to wade through comments to find the answer.

Comment: @RobH I probably should have mentioned I'm using Ubuntu Linux

Comment: @stefaanv it's just a guess - hopefully, ErwinJ will check whether it's right or wrong.

Comment: @ErwinJ. `taskset -p <pid>` shows the processor affinity as a bit mask.

Comment: @RobH Thanks. it says current affinity mask: f so that means all four processors i think.

Comment: @ErwinJ. Yes, I think so. That's what I see in my Ubuntu VM.

Comment: @ErwinJ also check that all the cores are active: grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A collegue of mine found the solution: clock() measures CPU cycles, so if two threads are running, it runs twice as fast. Timing with gettimeofday gave the expected result.

Comment: This also explains the windows discrepancies, as clock() under windows measures wall-clock seconds.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>First of all, with `i=0` `2.0/i` is dividing by zero</strike> (sorry, as Igor correctly noted in the comments, it's valid with floating point arithmetic, and, in this case, it results in +infinity.

Seconly, even if you fix that, your `testlock` function is probably going to be optimized to nothing, as the result is never used.

So at the moment you're just measuring the overhead of creating and joining threads, that's why the linear increase.

Comment: Toy code with bugs is not a good way to measure anything and expect it to have real world applicability.

Comment: You're mistaken. For IEEE floats, division of a finite nonzero float by 0 is well-defined and results in +infinity. Besides, testlock is not "optimized to nothing", at least not with MSVC10 (at any level of optimization).

Comment: Good point about the division by zero not sure why that doesn't cause problems. But the code doesn't get optimized away: I already checked that it takes 10 times as long when I increase the loop to 100000000 repetitions.

Comment: @Igor R.: thanks (&upvoted), I didn't know that. well, in that case the msvc compiler is really really dumb... gcc definitely doesn't emit any code for that if optimisation is enabled.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath just out of curiosity, what gcc version have you used with this code?

Comment: @Igor R.: I knew that gcc does these kind of optimizations, I wrote my answer without trying it. But now I compiled it just for you... 4.4.6-3 (that's the oldest I had here), but older versions should do the same thing.